# Linux C get network interface's master interface

Tags: c, linux, netlink

How would one get the master device of a network device they have an index of? I have looked into rtnetlink, but would prefer a simpler and more concise solution

Comment: @larsks could you put that in an answer? Nobody else bothered to respond and I find this satisfactory. As an extra to anyone reading, if_indextoname can be used to get name from index

Comment: I've moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the interface name you can read the value of `/sys/class/net/<interface>/master`. For example, on my system I have container with interface `veth3c732e7`. To find the associated bridge:

```
$ readlink /sys/class/net/veth3c732e7/master
../br-3d442aed4b81
```

We can confirm that information with the `ip link` command:

```
$ ip link show veth3c732e7
510: veth3c732e7@if509: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-3d442aed4b81 state UP mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 3e:66:b1:62:31:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
```

---

If you want to know how to do this without using `/sys`, the `ip` tool itself is open source. The relevant functions appear to be [here](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/main/ip/iplink.c#L1154) and [here](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/main/ip/ipaddress.c#L1004); it involves sending a netlink message and then receiving and parsing the response.